# Flutter build bundle on android stopping without error

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, build

I'm currently struggling on a problem when trying to build my flutter project on android studio.

The command I'm doing is

```
flutter build bundle --no-color --no-tree-shake-icons
```

The "--no-tree-shake-icons" is mandatory since I'm doing stuff in my app with icons. It wasn't a problem until now anyways.

When trying to execute this command, this is the result : [image]

As you can see, it is getting interrupted without telling me any errors. The weird think also is that when I'm instead trying to do an apk, it works ! But I must to an aab file to publish it...

[image]

I don't know if it helps but I'm signing my app in the build.gradle as followed :

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("C:\\Users\\AndroidStudioProjects\\my_project\\Certificate.jks")
        storePassword "**************************"
        keyAlias "my_amias"
        keyPassword "****************************"
    }
}
```

There is also my flutter doctor :

[image]

Tell me to add other informations if needed.

Thank you.